# Opening windows file dialog with selenium

Tags: c#, windows, google-chrome, selenium

I know this issue has been addressed a lot, but I haven't found a problem similar to mine, so please tell me if there's a solution.

I'm using selenium webdriver (chrome) and C# to test a web application.
In the application I have a button, which opens a windows file dialog in order to select and upload the file.

I am using Click() to click on the button and SendKeys() to paste the file's path in the windows dialog and to hit "Enter".
I'm not trying to control the dialog with selenium.
It's successful most of the time, but sometimes the dialog isn't opened once the button is clicked and it seems to be frozen for several minutes (it's impossible to click the button manually as well), but the test resumes as if the dialog had been opened. After 2-3 minutes the windows dialog finally appears, but needless to say that the entire test is messed up. 
It is not a problem in the program itself, as the problem never occurres when the click is preformed manually.

What could be the problem and how can I solve it?
Please have in mind I cannot change the program I'm testing.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without White using Microsoft UI Automation directly.

**Without TestStack White.** No sense to use the whole library for one window automation. White is wrapper only.

```
var FirefoxWindowElement = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty,"MozillaWindowClass"));
FirefoxWindowElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty,"#32770"))
//You can navigate directly to input field or just use the keyboard because input field is always focussed
SendKeys.SendWait("YOUR FILE PATH here");
Keyboard.Press(Key.Return);
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you create a wait for dialog?

```
        public void waitForElement()
    {
        while(!yourDialogElement.Displayed)
        {

            yourButtonElement.Click()
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000) // sleep for 1000 milliseconds

        }
    }
```

You will probably want to build a try/catch into that button click, and perhaps build a counter into your loop and pass a timeout limit.

Let me know if this works or if you need more help!

Comment: Thanks for answering, but the problem is that this is not a windows app so I can't access the dialog like that. I'm still looking for a way to access it at all. Also, I can't click the button again while the dialog isn't displayed yet - as I've mentioned it's completely frozen. I thought about adding a loop to wait for the dialog, but I can't find a way to check if it's displayed. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider adding a library called WHITE to your framework. This acts like Selenium but for Win32 applications and can handle most types of Windows dialog objects via Microsoft UI Automation.

With WHITE set up, you can add a method at the point in your code where the button is clicked by Selenium that opens up the dialog window. This method can poll for the presence of the dialog and if, after a set time, the window does not appear you could either fail the test there and then or try clicking the button again.

You could also poll indefinitely until the window appears if you are confident it always will. I would set an upper limit myself though to 5 minutes or whatever you feel is right here to prevent some sort of infinite loop situation.

Comment: This seemed to be the perfect solution, but I just can't find a way to "catch" the dialog just opened, without having its name or the application that has triggered it. Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: Do you need a way to identify the dialog? Download VisualVerify (a Microsoft tool) which acts as an object spy. It will allow you to inspect the dialog and find a property you can use to identify it with WHITE - https://uiautomationverify.codeplex.com/